# Random Shutdown Timer with powershell and no popup and hidden

Tags: powershell, random, cmd, restart, shutdown

Hi i try a cmd file or powershell file to shutdown a pc after a random time 20h and 24h with no popup message that the pc is shutting down in 10 minutes... and hidden

i try this

```
shutdown -r -t 86400 -c " "
```

Sekond  way:

```
start powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "sleep 86400; shutdown -r -t 00"
```

but without  random  time between 20h and 24h

Answer (score 1):

The PowerShell command to generate a random number in a range followed by the execution of shutdown.exe looks like that

```
$timeInSeconds = Get-Random -Minimum (20*3600) -Maximum (24*3600+1)
Start-Sleep -Seconds $timeInSeconds
shutdown.exe /r /t 0
```

if you really need a ugly oneliner than this might do what you need:\

```
powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "$timeInSeconds = Get-Random -Minimum (20*3600) -Maximum (24*3600+1); Start-Sleep -Seconds $timeInSeconds; shutdown.exe /r /t 0"
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that the OP's (other) requirements sound nefarious: hidden triggering of a shutdown at a random time, without the user  getting notified.

Comment: @mklement0 i have a mini pc this is working passiv and need some times a restart  to clear ram ....

Comment: @An-dir what you changed now  ???

Comment: Good to know, @hackuniverse. The change was mostly cosmetic, but you can always look at the post's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73991202/revisions). (Click on the small `edited <some time ago>` link below a post.